# Does the language in the movie Klaus actually make sense?

Tags: dialogue, klaus

So I recently watched the Netflix movie [Klaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_(film)).

In the movie there is a little girl who speaks Saami, as one of the other kids points out. 
My question is, does she really speak Saami and if she does, does she say things that make sense in the conversations?

Comment: At least one of the voice actors (https://www.imdb.com/name/nm10520267/?ref_=tt_cl_t2) has appeared in other movies in Saami and Norwegian.